# Compare timestamps stored as strings to a string formatted date

Tags: google-bigquery

`event_date` contains timestamps stored as strings.

```
1382623200
1382682600
1384248600
...
```

How can I `SELECT` rows where `event_date` is less than a string formatted date? This is my best attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [analytics:workspace.events] 
WHERE TIMESTAMP(event_date) < PARSE_UTC_USEC("2013-05-02 09:09:29");
```

I get all rows regardless of what date I pass to `PARSE_UTC_USEC()`

Answer (score 0):

Try below. Hope this helps

```
SELECT event_date, TIMESTAMP(event_date) as ts
FROM -- [analytics:workspace.events] 
(
  SELECT event_date FROM
    (SELECT '1382623200' AS event_date),
    (SELECT '1382682600' AS event_date),
    (SELECT '1384248600' AS event_date)
)
WHERE TIMESTAMP(event_date) < PARSE_UTC_USEC("2013-10-25 07:30:00")
```

above is just example - you should use your table in real life:

```
SELECT event_date, TIMESTAMP(event_date) as ts
FROM [analytics:workspace.events] 
WHERE TIMESTAMP(event_date) < PARSE_UTC_USEC("2013-10-25 07:30:00")
```

Comment: It's not just 3 event dates, so I can't list all of them. The list goes on.

Comment: i used just 3 events for you as example to simplify "testing". see addition to my answer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `event_date` strings represent Unix seconds. Try this using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"):

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT x, event_date
  FROM UNNEST(['1382623200',
               '1382682600',
               '1384248600']) AS event_date WITH OFFSET x
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT * REPLACE (TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(event_date AS INT64)) AS event_date)
  FROM T
)
WHERE event_date < '2013-05-02 09:09:29';
```

The subquery converts the `event_date` string into a timestamp using the `REPLACE` clause.